# reading a row of ints (with spaces) from a text file into an array? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, arraylist

So im trying to read a text file that contains:
 "0  6  13  0  0  75  33  0  0  0  4  29  21  0  86  0  32  66  0  0"

I have tried various different ways but none seemed to have worked. How could I read these numbers from the file and store them into an array?
Thanks

Comment: `readLine()`  by `BufferedReader` and `split()` by space.

Comment: and `Integer.parseInt()`

How do I type the code block "apostrophes"? I just copied them XD

Comment: Use an arraylist. Arrays have fixed sizes..

Comment: @Kuma they're backquotes.  On most keyboards, it's to the left of the 1 key.  But on some keyboards, it's in a different place.

Answer (score 1):

You could use java.util.Scanner and

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
boolean quit = false;
while (!quit){
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
            int a = keyIn.getNextInt)
    ,,,
```

Or, you could read the line into a String and the peel off each of the numbers by splitting on the blank.

```
String source = line.trim() + " ";

loc = 0;
while (loc < source.length) {
  int i = source.indexOf(" ");
  int number = new INteger(source.substring(0, i);)
  source = source.substring(i+1);
```

...

Comment: thanks! but where would i be saying which text file it should get the data from

Comment: This snippet of code reads data from the keyboard.  Do you want to create a file on your computer from which to read the data?